# Is there a way to encode character variables into numeric variables in a full dataset

Tags: r, match

I am trying to convert how my contemporary groups are coded.

Currently They are in the the character format of "240009T2017", "240009T2018", "240056P2018", "240108T2016" for approximately 40 groups. I would like to recode them instead as 1,2,3,4, ...

I found some of my answer from "R: Encode character variables into numeric

```
x <- c("240009T2017", "240009T2018", "240056P2018", "240108T2016")
dat$hyn <- match(x, unique(x))
```

But I am not sure how to convert it for the whole data set. Ideally, every time "240009T2017" appears in the contemporary group column, then it would convert it to 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a trick for that with a factor, that will take care of duplicated values. Here the code:

```
#Data
x <- c("240009T2017", "240009T2018", "240056P2018", "240108T2016","240009T2017")
#Conversion to factor
y <- as.numeric(as.factor(x))
```

The outputs:

```
x
[1] "240009T2017" "240009T2018" "240056P2018" "240108T2016" "240009T2017"

y
[1] 1 2 3 4 1
```

Comment: I have upvoted but in my tests the OP's `match(x, unique(x))` is order(s) of magnitude faster. (The plural depended on fraction of unique values in `x`, the less the smaller the difference).

Comment: @RuiBarradas Oh it is a great suggestion and advice !!!